# CiviCRM birthday error PHP

Tags: drupal, error

Since I've updated my installation of Drupal - CiviCRM to version 4.7.27 we got some errors. If we edit or add a user we can't select the birthday for the user. Like you see on the screenshots, we get some initialization errors and the date picker only allows one date (the date of today).

Anyone who can help figure this out? Thx!
[image]

Comment: Works OK on mine. You tried emptying your templates_c folder?

Comment: Yes I've done that now, but it didn't work.

Comment: The errors are only notices, not necessarily the cause of your reported issue. Since it's a javascript thingy, the key place to look is the 'console' (usually, right click and "inspect" pulls up the window you need).

Comment: Smart... but i took a look and there are no errors there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some debugging, i found out the CRM_Core_SelectValues was overridden by the com.klangsoft.flexiblejobs extension. After disabling this module or updating the code the problem was resolved.